# Java Struts - Dead Link Checker

Tags: struts, httpurlconnection

I need to check a set intranet sites. I tried to use the below code. (Just got this code by random search on the internet). I called this method on my action class. But most of the sites where going into the exception part. I was getting Protocol exceptions and `UnknownHostException` even though I was able to open these sites from my browser.

Code for reference:

```
public boolean isLive(String link) {  
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;  
  try {  
    URL url = new URL(link);  
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");  
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000); /* timeout after 5s if can't connect */  
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000); /* timeout after 5s if the page is too slow */  
    urlConnection.connect();  
    String redirectLink = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");  
    if (redirectLink != null && !link.equals(redirectLink)) {  
      return isLive(redirectLink);  
    } else {  
      return urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;  
    }  
  } catch (Exception e) {  
    return false;  
  } finally {  
    if (urlConnection != null) {  
      urlConnection.disconnect();  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think No Problem with the code.
You have a connection timeout of 5 seconds

```
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000)
```

Any query that takes more than 5 seconds will be considered a dead link.Your Browser have much longer timeout than your code so you are able to browse those sites in the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting protocol exceptions and unknown host exceptions we'd need to know more in order to help. Is your machine configured to go through a proxy? Do you have host definitions that wouldn't be shared by your app container's user?

Also, consider using something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to wrap up stuff like this rather than doing it manually; just too much work.